# instagram feed slideshow into website

Tags: jquery, slideshow, instagram

I am using this plugin http://projects.craftedpixelz.co.uk/jqinstapics/ to show instagram's pictures into a website, i really like this plug in because when you click the picture it sends you to your instagram not to some page like other widgets and the only 2 things i need are:

```
<script>
    $("#instagram").jqinstapics({
      "user_id": "",
      "access_token": "",
      "count": 10
    });
</script>

<ul id="instagram"></ul>
```

Now i need to make the feed and slideshow instead of showing the 10 pictures in a grid type of thing i need to show one and the fade and show the second and so on.

Any ideas? I am really need to jquery...thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're not too familiar with jQuery you might want to look into Bootstrap's Carousel plugin.  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [slidetagram](https://github.com/achvaicer/slidetagram) ?
It's free and open-source.